# Xcode 8 iOS Simulator is not prompting for location services authorization in my Swift 3 project

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift3, cllocationmanager

I have followed the apple developer [guide on location services](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH1-SW1).

I have included the `info.plist` key value pair:

key: `Privacy - Location Always Usage Description`

value: `The application myTestApp needs access to location services even in the background`

I have created an instance of `CLLocationManager` as a class variable of the view controller:

`var locationManager = CLLocationManager()`

I have code in the view controller `viewDidLoad()` function that assigns the delegate and checks for the current status:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    switch status {
    case .denied, .restricted, .notDetermined, .authorizedWhenInUse :
        print("The switch detected a state other than always")
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    default:
        print("Services Authorized")
    }
```

Yet, when I build and run the application after making small changes it does not prompt for user access, and even worse, when it does sometimes work it thinks the user is in the middle of the Atlantic ocean at Lat: 0.0 and Long: 0.0.

Is there anything outside of the code I need to do so that I can recreate the user experience of authorizing the application and then seeing it zoom to a real location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The user permission prompt is one time only. Once it is allowed,
>   device would fetch user location automatically from that point.

**Try setting the custom location in the simulator via these two methods.**

**1. Using the simulator menu actions**

[image]

**2. Using the Xcode debugger options**

[image]

Comment: Because it is a one time event, you would think you could delete the app and reinstall it.  That does not work. iOS will keep the permission around for about 1 day even if the app is deleted.  It does this to allow a user to remove apps and reinstall without having to approve the permissions again.

Comment: @umar-farooque and @ryantxr thank you for the help. In addition to the answer you provided to get the location services right, I also discovered that you can click on `Simulator->Reset Content & Settings` in the sim menu bar and it will clear all app authorizations so you can get a full simulation of the installation and authorization process.

Comment: @ZacSketches yes, it resets the simulator and deletes the installed apps and their settings as well.

Answer (score 1):

The simulator handles location a bit differently from the device. I'd suggest pushing the app over to the device itself and running from there to see how it asks for permission and make sure it is giving the right location. It's very easy to do and very helpful for testing with apps that use access to location services.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html

Essentially, plug phone in, select it from the list of devices to simulate with, press play and accept your developer access on the phone to run the app from your device.

Comment: I picked the other answer because it specifically addressed how to better run in the simulator, but I am moving onto device testing next so I made a note of the link you shared to review next.